# Highlighting of (too) long sentences

Tags: packages, word-count

I'd like to improve the readability of a very long document. To do so, I'd like to have sentences with more than x words highlighted in the `pdf`.

Is there a way to realise this (either via a package, or even using the compiled `pdf`)?

Comment: You might want to let us know about more about the system you're working in: there may be a better way to achieve this using editor macros for example.  How about a command-line script which would depend on the system you're working on (I'm thinking of something like a regexp that matches >x spaces between characters in the class [.?!] and wraps the whole sentence in `\textcolor{red}{...}`.  When writing long documents I put each sentence on a line of its own, long lines are then easy to spot, and unlike my regexp approach this will pick up sentences which are long because of many long words.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer! I use TeXstudio to create the final *.pdf file on Windows 7. The included *.tex files are written in Notepad++ and/or vim. I use a lot of packages and formulae, thus, I guess working on the *.pdf is easier?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way of doing this is using Texstudio ([link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/)), as it automatically highlight sentences longer than 40 words. [image]